# Trying to delete photos with Facebook C# SDK and issuing a POST request to Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, silverlight-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk, photo

I want my Silverlight app to let the user delete a photo from his Facebook account, photo that I have already successfully retrieved from there and shown to the user, but the photo I want to delete is never deleted. Delete operation is supposed to be supported by the Facebook API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), and I tried these two ways:

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                 {
                                     {"method", "delete"}
                                 };


        fb.PostAsync(id, parameters);
```

This one returns an exception message from Facebook API ("Unknown method"), and then I tried this other way:

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
fb.DeleteAsync(id);
```

being "id" the id of the photo I want to delete in both cases. This way I get a positive response but the photo is simply not deleted, what is wrong? Do I need an extra permission for deleting? I didn't found anything related to that in the Facebook documentation, I assumed that it was enough being able to grant permissions to access the photos, thing that I already do... I need some help.

Comment: you can't delete the photo as @tomconte mentioned, but seems like there is a bug when method is delete, it's using it as rest api instead of graph api (though it has nothing to deal with deleting photo) You might want to create a new issue on this at codeplex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete photos using the API ; you can check the Photo API doc at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/ and a long-running forum thread at http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=96837

Comment: Ok, in the link I posted they talked about deleting as if it was possible to remove almost any object having its id... thanks!